# Symfony3 refresh template with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, foreach

I try to update the variable of PHP foreach loop in a twig template with ajax but without success.

Here is my template :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="uk-container uk-container-large">
        <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        {% for article in articles %}

                <div class="uk-width-1-6@xl uk-width-1-5@l uk-width-1-4@m uk-width-1-3@s">
                    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default">
                        <div class="uk-card-media-top">
                            <img id="image" src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(article, 'imageFile') | imagine_filter('article_thumb') }}" alt="{{ article.name }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-card-body">
                            <h3 id="name" class="uk-card-title">{{ article.name }}</h3>
                            <p id="description">{{ article.description | truncate(40) }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my javascript :

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: Routing.generate("ajax_request"),
            data: { brand: selectedBrand }
            //dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                $('#image').html(data[i].image);
                $('#name').html(data[i].name);
                $('#description').html(data[i].description);

            }
        })
```

### EDIT

Since I found a solution that works but I do not know how display the images because of VichUploaderBundle, you have an idea?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: Routing.generate("ajax_request"),
            data: { brand: selectedBrand }
            //dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {

            $('.uk-text-center').children().html('');
            var htmlText = '';

            for ( var key in data ) {
                htmlText += '<div class="uk-width-1-6@xl uk-width-1-5@l uk-width-1-4@m uk-width-1-3@s">';
                htmlText += '<div class="uk-card uk-card-default">';
                htmlText += '<div class="uk-card-media-top">';
                htmlText += "<img src='{{ vich_uploader_asset(article, \'imageFile\') | imagine_filter(\'article_thumb\') }}' alt='{{ article.name }}'>";
                htmlText += '</div>';
                htmlText += '<div class="uk-card-body">';
                htmlText += '<h3 class="uk-card-title">' + data[key].name + '</h3>';
                htmlText += '<p>' + data[key].description + '</p>';
                htmlText += '</div>';
                htmlText += '</div>';
                htmlText += '</div>';
            }

            $('.uk-text-center').html(htmlText);
        })
```

Here is the debug of my JSON data in the "done" promise of my ajax function :

```
[
    {"id":207,"name":"article 5","category":"sweat","brand":"adidas","model":"boze","gender":"homme","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id ultricies eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.","quantity":61,"size":"M","price":34,"image":"ceinture.jpg","imageSize":null,"added":{"date":"2017-10-17 01:33:57.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"updated":null,"deleted":null,"sold":null},
    {"id":209,"name":"article 7","category":"sous-vêtements","brand":"adidas","model":"running","gender":"femme","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id ultricies eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.","quantity":53,"size":"M","price":100,"image":"IMG_7846.jpg","imageSize":null,"added":{"date":"2017-10-17 01:33:57.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"updated":null,"deleted":null,"sold":null},
    {"id":220,"name":"article 18","category":"chaussures","brand":"adidas","model":"running","gender":"homme","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id ultricies eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.","quantity":3,"size":"M","price":14,"image":"black_sweat.jpg","imageSize":null,"added":{"date":"2017-10-17 01:33:57.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"updated":null,"deleted":null,"sold":null},
    {"id":229,"name":"article 27","category":"sweat","brand":"adidas","model":"boze","gender":"femme","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id ultricies eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.","quantity":54,"size":"M","price":63,"image":"blue_jeans.jpg","imageSize":null,"added":{"date":"2017-10-17 01:33:57.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"updated":null,"deleted":null,"sold":null},
    {"id":231,"name":"article 29","category":"pantalons","brand":"adidas","model":"smoked","gender":"femme","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id ultricies eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.","quantity":96,"size":"L","price":16,"image":"black_sweat.jpg","imageSize":null,"added":{"date":"2017-10-17 01:33:57.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"updated":null,"deleted":null,"sold":null},
    {"id":232,"name":"article 30","category":"chaussures","brand":"adidas","model":"boze","gender":"homme","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id ultricies eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.","quantity":99,"size":"XXL","price":56,"image":"black_pants.jpg","imageSize":null,"added":{"date":"2017-10-17 01:33:57.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"updated":null,"deleted":null,"sold":null}
]
```

Comment: html document can only have one element with that id, `<img id="image"`, `name` and `description` won't work on the for loop because you have several elements with the same id. Does the data in your script always have the same length? How do you know how to hook up the data to what element? Does the data have an id so you can use that to give an id to elements and then hook up new data?

Comment: Yes you're right, I did not pay attention to id. Since I found a solution that works but I don't know how display the images because of VichUploader, you have an idea?

Comment: Is that the symfony bundle? https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle then are you sure you get the right urll to the image? https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/generating_urls.md

Comment: Can you please update your question with the json string of your data? 'JSON.stringify(data,null,2)'

Comment: Yes it's the VichUploaderBundle to handle the file uploading. I have updated my question with the JSON like you asked.